# Does a drive mapping stay mapped if a different user logs onto a PC

Tags: mapped-drive, drive-mapping

So I want to be able to map a drive but when I log out of the PC and someone else logs, I want that drive to still stay mapped.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this with login scripts

Comment: Cool thanks! Do you happen to have those scripts or know the scripts etc?

Comment: I would google that if I where you. If you do, one comment is that GPO is better, if that is relevant. 
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/677818/adding-mapped-drive-via-logon-script/